# Devise user signup fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I installed devise and created an admin user through my seeds.rb

```
Role.create!(:name => "Super Admin") 
Permission.create!(:subject_class => "all", :action => "manage")
role = Role.find_by_name("Super Admin")
role.permissions << Permission.where(:subject_class => "all", :action => "manage")
user = User.new(:email => "admin@admin.de", password:"adminadmin", password_confirmation:"adminadmin")
user.role = role  
user.save!
```

But if I now try to register a new user over the sign up page I get following error on submit:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in Devise::RegistrationsController#create 
TinyTds::Error: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.users' with unique index 'index_users_on_reset_password_token'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [users] ([created_at], [email], [encrypted_password], [role_id], [updated_at]) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)', N'@0 datetime, @1 nvarchar(255), @2 nvarchar(255), @3 int, @4 datetime', @0 = '2014-07-11T08:50:33.892', @1 = N'user@user.de', @2 = N'$2a$10$pfsgr9knTUGghhwJFmoaLOvWdAUptntlFuVL3/18bKRCs7ZZyFheK', @3 = 2, @4 = '2014-07-11T08:50:33.892'
```

My `admin` object looks like this:

```
id  email   encrypted_password  reset_password_token    reset_password_sent_at  remember_created_at sign_in_count   current_sign_in_at  last_sign_in_at current_sign_in_ip  last_sign_in_ip created_at  updated_at  role_id
1   admin@admin.de  $2a$10$/slcMrZGywmS6zDcNxKsl.Ypaxafucvb0Pg1l2SPuy11dYDkU/x/e    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   2014-07-11 08:50:13.093 2014-07-11 08:50:13.093 127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   2014-07-11 08:48:54.267 2014-07-11 08:50:13.097 1
```

Any ideas what could cause that? It sounds to me like the reset password token cant be the same but its automatically NIL on creation so that doenst even make sense.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

Had to delete the named index in my user table in the database and now it works fine.